# i am using proxy api to test and scrape movies from imdb but all i get is [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, scrapy, web-crawler

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scraper_api import ScraperAPIClient
client = ScraperAPIClient('hiding the key')



class MoviesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "movies"

    def start_requests(self):
        
        urls = ["https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=drama&groups=top_250&sort=user_rating,desc"]
        for link in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(client.scrapyGet(url=link,render=True),callback=self.parse_item)

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//h3[@class="lister-item-header"]/a'), callback="parse_item", follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):

        yield {'link':response.url}
```

[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fsearch%2Ftitle%2F%3Fgenres%3Ddrama%26groups%3Dtop_250%26sort%3Duser_rating%2Cdesc&api_key=8ccf268c7e3c965da0777f5594598b9d&render=true&scraper_sdk=python%5C\>](https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fsearch%2Ftitle%2F%3Fgenres%3Ddrama%26groups%3Dtop_250%26sort%3Duser_rating%2Cdesc&api_key=8ccf268c7e3c965da0777f5594598b9d&render=true&scraper_sdk=python%5C%5C%3E) (referer: None)

2023-02-19 17:48:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 [https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fsearch%2Ftitle%2F%3Fgenres%3Ddrama%26groups%3Dtop_250%26sort%3Duser_rating%2Cdesc&api_key=8ccf268c7e3c965da0777f5594598b9d&render=true&scraper_sdk=python%5C\>](https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fsearch%2Ftitle%2F%3Fgenres%3Ddrama%26groups%3Dtop_250%26sort%3Duser_rating%2Cdesc&api_key=8ccf268c7e3c965da0777f5594598b9d&render=true&scraper_sdk=python%5C%5C%3E)

{'link': 'https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fsearch%2Ftitle%2F%3Fgenres%3Ddrama%26groups%3Dtop_250%26sort%3Duser_rating%2Cdesc&api_key=8ccf268c7e3c965da0777f5594598b9d&render=true&scraper_sdk=python'}

i was expecting to get ['link': name of the link]

Comment: that is what the last result is.   the first 2 are just debug logs the tell you that the request was successful, you might be able to find the original link by itself in the response meta.  Some api's put it there.

Comment: yield {'link':response.url} this should get all the links inside h3 tag restrict_xpaths='//h3[@class="lister-item-header" but i am getting only one link that is page itself also thankyou now i learn what first two response are in crawlspider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a standard `spider` instead of the `crawlspider`.  If all you are trying to scrape is the urls then this is the way to go anyway since this way you only make a single request instead of one for each link.

```
class MoviesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "movies"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ["https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=drama&groups=top_250&sort=user_rating"]
        for link in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(client.scrapyGet(url=link,render=True))

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//h3/a/@href").getall():
            full_link = response.urljoin(link)
            yield {'link': full_link}
```

Comment: so here is a thing i am noob and it works perfectly with scrapy.spider what i am trying to do is use Proxy Api with crawl spider

Comment: Is there a particular reason why? @frozen

Comment: can you recommend me a book or a course to get better at this, also when to use scrapy.spider and when to use CrawlSpider? no reason at all just testing proxy api out

Comment: the [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) and [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy) is the best reading material you can find.

Comment: now i get this out put {'link': 'https://api.scraperapi.com/title/tt1345836/?ref_=adv_li_tt'}
2023-02-19 18:45:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fsearch%2Ftitle%2F%3Fgenres%3Ddrama%26groups%3Dtop_250%26sort%3Duser_rating&api_key=8ccf268c7e3c965da0777f5594598b9d&render=true&scraper_sdk=python> this is with using scrapy.spider

Comment: are you trying to get `response.url` again?  or is that just using my example? @frozen

Comment: i used your example and its WORKING perfectly